# How do I alter the opacity of an image but not overlayed text using Bootstrap's carousel component

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap v4 to create a carousel that contains an image with caption text. I want the image to be faded but the text unaffected. I have tried various non Bootstrap solutions but I just can't get anything to work. Please help :(

Link to development site; http://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/mlb/

Code:

```
<div id="home-page-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#home-page-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#home-page-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> 

    <!-- Slide 1 -->
    <div class="carousel-item active"> <img src="<?php echo SITE_IMG . 'L1.jpg'; ?>" alt="Liverpool City Centre">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>This is a title</h3>
        <p>This is some text that is relevant to the title above</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slide 2 -->

    <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="<?php echo SITE_IMG . 'L1.jpg'; ?>" alt="Liverpool City Centre">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>This is a title</h3>
        <p>This is some text that is relevant to the title above</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Previous/Next controls --> 
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#home-page-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#home-page-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> </div>

<!-- Center the image -->
<style scoped>
.carousel-item img{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: check this out [Static text on Slider](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-static-headline-caption)

Comment: @Suraj - How does this help me? I can't see anything about opacity?

Comment: Why not just set the `opacity` value on the images? The captions aren't children of them so won't inherit the opacity

Comment: @Andy - I've tried that and it affects the text as well. I'll update the dev site to show that now

Comment: @Andy - I stand corrected, that worked. When I first tried it, I was using white text which didn't help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this HTML

```
<div class="carousel-item"> <img src="<?php echo SITE_IMG . 'L1.jpg'; ?>" alt="Liverpool City Centre">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>This is a title</h3>
        <p>This is some text that is relevant to the title above</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You're asking for:

```
.carousel-item img {
     opacity: /* whatever */
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you just need to reduce the opacity of the image itself:

```
.carousel-item img {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; /* IE 8 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);                                         /* IE 5-7 */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;                                                 /* Netscape/Firefox */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;                                               /* Safari 1.x */
  opacity: 0.5;                                                      /* Good browsers */
}
```